# In Xcode which audio file types loop seamlessly?

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, loops

So, I have read that if you want to make an audio sound play and loop, mp3 doesn't work well because it has a gap. Are there any file types that work and when looped don't have a gap? If so, which types?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which audio types can loop without a gap in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439174/which-audio-types-can-loop-without-a-gap-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

For me, .aiff works best. It loops seamlessly and has a small file size, but .wav works too.